# I need some help to solve a plane geometry problem.

Tags: geometry, contest-math

I been doing some geometry of some problems from Olympiads. I found one that I really haven't been able to solve. It's been 3 days since I
found it. I have to admit that I haven't been all the time doing this problem, but I've spend around 3 and half hours doing this problem and I couldn't really crack the nut.

> In an acute triangle $ABC$, an arbitrary point $P$ is chosen on the altitude $AH$. The points $E$ and $F$ are the midpoints of $AC$ and $AB$, respectively. The perpendiculars from $E$ on $CP$ and from $F$ on $BP$ intersect at the point $K$. Show that $KB = KC$.

Well, at first I tried Euclidean geometry and tried to use the midpoint theorem and some constructions and I even discovered something cool about the circle with radius $KC$, then I realized I could prove that $K$ lies on the perpendicular bisector of $BC$, use the Pythagorean theorem and I even noticed that the point $K$ was the intersection of 3 perpendicular lines, so I could hypthecally prove that $K$ was the circuncenter of some triangle involving these sides.

At the end , I did use Cartesian coordinates, but, there were so many equations and really, didn't get do much satisfaction.

Does someone has some good idea on how to solve it with Euclidean geometry?

[image]

[image]

I pretty much did all of that.

Comment: Please try to create a diagram representing your interpretation of the problem, via either online software, your own graphical software, or by taking a picture of a diagram on scratch paper.  This will help reviewers grasp the problem.  Further, for help managing images at MathSE, see the **Edit-Images** section of [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).   ...see next comment

Comment: Also, please edit your posting to show your work, as discussed in the article linked to in the previous comment.  Since this problem is apparently not from a book or class, it is plausible that you haven't been given the appropriate training for the problem.  Still, please indicate your Geometry training, and any **tools** that you think are pertinent, as discussed in the **Edit-Tools** section of the article linked to in the previous comment.

Comment: Where did you find it?

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2717996p23638262

Comment: @user2661923 I don't really know, how to proceed, but, I believe that , midpoint theorem, similar and congruent triangles, points of a triangle, homothety, and I also saw  radical axis between $K$ and $E$ or $F$ and $K$ all of them may lead to progress or the solution.

Comment: My only criticism of your current posting is that the 2nd *image* in your posting, the image of showing your work, should be deleted by you, and replaced by writing the pertinent Math directly into the posting, via [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E',F'$ the midpoint of $BP, CP$ and $K'$ the circumcenter of $BCP$. Then we can show $|EE'|=|FF'|=\frac{1}{2}|AP|$ and both lines are perpendicular to $BC$ using the Intercept theorem. Because $EK,FK$ are parallel to $E'K',F'K'$ we conclude that $KK'$ is perpendicular to $BC$ and therefore $K$ lies on the perpendicular bisector of $BC$.